# how to store confiq files in gitlab

Tags: bash, gitlab, scheduled-tasks

In below script there are config files (ppsit ppdev ppdev2 ppuat)how to store confiq files in gitlab and schedule it to run every 2 hour .

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -eux
files=("ppsit ppdev ppdev2 ppuat")
for file in $files
do
source $file
echo $file

now=$(date +%s)

keytool -list -v -keystore /$path/$env  -storepass $password | sed -nr 's/^Alias name:\s*(.*)$/\1/p;s/Valid from:.*until: *(.*)/\1/p' |
  paste - - |
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r alias expires ; do
    expires_at=$(date -d "$expires" +%s)
    if ((expires_at < now)) ; then
      echo -e "$alias" | tee "$file-out.txt" 
      echo -e "$file-out.txt" 
      fi
  done
 done
```

i have written shell script which will list all the expire certificates
i need to run it every two hour using gitlab or using openshift as am not aware how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried a [Gitlab scheduled pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html)?

Comment: Is above script work with gitlab scheduled pipeline ?

Comment: Any bash script, yes.

Comment: Ok will follow that document u shared ,Thanks a lot

Comment: The above script has some config files(ppsit, ppdev etc) how to save those file in gitlab ?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/

Comment: I'll add, however, that this doesn't really make sense from an OpenShift perspective: so running the command will only check the certs in the container you are running it in.

Comment: Actually the next part of script is to delete the expire certificate so for these reason thought to run inside pod

Comment: @FareedBeig:  I saw you msg on your deleted question from yesterday *"But how to store config files in gitlab"*. I have no experience with gitlab, but it would seem like a man page or tutorial for gitlab would have that listed as a #1 resource.  I searched here on S.O.  for gitlab config and founc 3200~ Q/A. ....

Comment: Searching the interweb for `gitlab config file location` showed many help resources. If after reading these you still don't know what to do, I recommend you post a new question and show your code of what you have tried to "store the config file". Then readers can help correct your understanding of how this feature works. Don't make readers guess what you have tried! OK? (-;! Good luckk.

Comment: One more thing! Did my link to info about crontab help you? Are you even working in an environment that supports crontabs? In either case, I recommend that you focus on one step at a time. Get your config file problem solved so you can execute a solution from the cmd line (or make a change to some config item via a webpage/user interface), then incorporate any code solutions into your shell script. Finally, learn the tech for your enviroment (crontab?) to run you job every 2 hrrs. Good luck.

Comment: OK, after reading your code and comments from other carefully, I see I have glossed over some important points. Links to documentation has been provided and it seems the doc doesn't tell you what yo need. Sorry I have to quite writing now, Much of the above is not helpful. Sorrry about that. Maybe some helps. WIll check back later. Good luck.

Comment: @FareedBeig : Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: @shellter : still didnt dont know how to store confiq files in gitlab to schedule it .

Comment: That is a better title for your question. (How to ....). Let's clean this up and I will put a bounty on it for you. Read all the comments (some of mine you can ignore), and try to improve your question so people know what you have done without reading all the comments. Then I will delete my comments and put the bounty on. And we'll hope you get a good answer. Busy today, so will check in as I can, but you may not hear back from me until tomorrow.

Comment: @FareedBeig See above. Still busy. may not be around until much later or tomorrow.

Comment: @shellter :sure

Comment: Are you going to make changes to you question per the comments above (not just mine)? Think about this from a reader's perspective. Does the all the code really matter? The basic problem is **" how to store confiq files in gitlab"**. What's the smallest script that demonstates that problem?  If the documentation about using the scheduler isn't helping you, that is a separate question.

Comment: @DMalan : Jumping back 2 weeks, can you tell FareedBeig where to store config files in gitlab? Note the lines in the script `files=("ppsit ppdev ppdev2 ppuat")
for file in $files ;do
 source $file ; ....`  This assumes the $files are in the $PWD of gitlab (and possible the script).  Does he need to prefix like `source $MY_CFG_DIR/$file` ? I, obviously am not a gitlab person (-;. Thanks for any help.